# Playing a video in new desktop created by createdesktop()

Tags: c++, wmp

I have an application( has a feature like a customised screen saver) wherein im creating a new desktop using createdesktop and then switched to new desktop using the call switchdesktop() and getthreadesktoop() Im so far successful created and switching to this new desktop and coming back to old desktop. The problem is when i create a window and play a video using WMP. Though im able to hear voice, i cannot see the video instead see a blank screen. Without the newly created desktop everything works fine. That is if i dont create a new desktoo n switch then things worknas expected

Answer (score 0):

You see a blank screen and hearing voice means that your player is actually working, it is just the newly created desktop is displaying and your player program in running in the old desktop. Try run your player in the new desktop.